# Subscript R notation for the finite fields

Tags: finite-field, identity-based-encryption, notation, prime-field

I'm trying to understand the notation used in the literature for Pairing-based cryptography.

I know (and I hope I've understood it well) from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) that **$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the finite field of prime order $p$**, where

- $p$ is the order of the field
- $q$ and the characteristic of the field and $q=p^n$

I came across this notation [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/064.pdf) and [there](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring04/L25.pdf) while researching the Identity-Based Encryption (Boneh-Franklin): $$s \in_R\mathbb{Z}^*_q$$

The $\mathbb{Z}^*$ means that the finite field is provided with the multiplication operation.

But the $_R$ confuses me, as I can't find its meaning on the web.

Could somebody explain it?

PS: are the following notations equivalent? $GF(p)$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: The $_R$ has nothing to do with the field — it is associated to $\in$! To quote your first link: "For a set $S$, by $a\in_RS$, we mean that $a$ is randomly chosen from $S$."

Comment: Oh, shame on me ^^. And for the notation equivalence ?

Comment: If $p\in \mathbb P$ (with $\mathbb P$ being the set of all primes)  then the notations $GF(p); \mathbb Z_p; \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z; \mathbb F_p$ are equivalent.

Comment: Note that depending on the context $\mathbb Z_p$ is also used for the $p$-adic integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote yyyyyyy [from the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34618/notation-for-the-finite-fields#comment80824_34618):

> The $_R$ has nothing to do with the field — it is associated to $\in$!
>   To quote your first link: "For a set $S$, by $a\in_R S$, we mean that
>   $a$ is randomly chosen from $S$."

and to quote SEJPM [from the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34618/notation-for-the-finite-fields#comment80828_34618):

> If $p\in \mathbb P$ (with $\mathbb P$ being the set of all primes)
>   then the notations $GF(p);\mathbb Z_p;\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z;\mathbb
>  F_p$ are equivalent.

Comment: I made this a community wiki (for which nobody receives reputation) because the answer is trivial (for many people at least) and because yyyyyyy did the "major" work. (And I really hate comment-answered question which don't have a formal answer)

Comment: Another (realted) question : does $X =\langle U, V \rangle$ mean that $X$ is the concatenation of $U$ and $V$ ?

Comment: @EisenHeim, depends on the context.